# react how to setup private routes that can only be accessed when someone is signed in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, google-signin

I'm trying to make a website with react-google-login SSO authentication, and I'd like to make a private route where if no user is logged in, no one can access those routes and even see the sidebar component. And will be always be redirected to the login page even if they try to access the route through the url.

Here's my app.js

```
  function App() {
  const [value,setValue] = useState()
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState()

  
  return (
    <>
    <Column style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Row horizontal="start" style={{ backgroundColor: "#0C5494" }}>
        <a href="/">
        <img alt="logo" className="photo" src={logo}/>
        </a> 
        </Row>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Row >
      <Column
            flexGrow={1}
          >
        <PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/" element={<Sidebar/>}></Route>
        </PrivateRoute>
        </Column>
        <Column
            vertical="start"
            flexGrow={100}
           // style={{ backgroundColor: "pink"}}
          >
          <div className="mainContent">
          <AuthContext.Provider value={{loggedIn,setLoggedIn}}>
          <TableCountContext.Provider value={{value,setValue}}>
          <PrivateRoute>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<RealHome/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/search" element={<Home/>}></Route>
          
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}></Route>
     
          <Route path="/FAQ" element={<Faq/>}></Route>
         
          <Route path="/Search-sec" element={<SearchSec/>}></Route>
          </PrivateRoute>
          </TableCountContext.Provider>
          </AuthContext.Provider>
          </div>
          
          </Column>
        </Row>
        
      </BrowserRouter>
      </Column>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

here's my google login button:

```
 export default function GoogleLoginButton() {
    const clientId = "myGoogleID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    const [showLoginButton, setShowLoginButton] = useState(true)
    const [showLogoutButton, setShowLogoutButton] = useState(false)
    const {loggedIn,setLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext)
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const onLoginSuccess = (res) =>{
        console.log("Login Success:", res.profileObj);
        setShowLoginButton(false)
        setShowLogoutButton(true)
        setLoggedIn(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'))
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'))
        console.log(loggedIn)
        navigate(`/`)
    }
    const onLoginFailure = (res)=>{
        console.log("Login Failed:", res)
    }

    const onSignoutSuccess = () =>{
        alert("You have been signed out successfully.")
        setShowLoginButton(true)
        setShowLogoutButton(false)
        setLoggedIn(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'))
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', false);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'))
        console.log(loggedIn)
    }
  
    
    return (
        <div>
            {showLoginButton ?
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
                onFailure={onLoginFailure}
                cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
                isSignedIn={true}
            /> : null }
            {showLogoutButton ?
            <GoogleLogout
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Sign Out"
                onLogoutSuccess={onSignoutSuccess}
            /> : null}
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's my PrivateRoute.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
import {Navigate,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import { AuthContext } from "./Contexts"

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext)

  return (
    <Routes>
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return loggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
      }}
    ></Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Here's my Contexts.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const TableCountContext = createContext(null)
export const AuthContext = createContext(false)
```

Comment: Add some routes conditionally based on whether the user is logged in. Then a default / catch-all which redirects as desired for other urls. The latter can be accomplished with `Redirect` in `react-router` < v6, and with `Navigate` for >= v6.

Comment: @fast-reflexes i've updated the codes displayed on my question based from my understanding of your comment but I still can access my private routes when i type it in the url.

Comment: Added an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is for `react-router` version 6.

Add routes conditionally based on whether you are logged in or not and add one or more redirects depending on what you want:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={"/"} element={ <StartPage/> }/>
    <Route path={"/example"} element={ <ExamplePage/> }/>
    <Route path={"/otherpage"} element={ <AnotherPage/> }/>
    {
        isLoggedIn ?
            [ 
                // add as many as you'd like here
                <Route path={"/loggedinpage"} element={ <LoggedInPage/> }/>
            ]
            :
            null
    }
    // take care of redirects for all paths that doesn't match the defined
    <Route path={"*"} element={ <Navigate replace to={ "/" }/> }/>
</Routes>
```

When there are no paths defined for logged in users, those paths will be matched by the catch-all and the user will be redirected to `/` whereas when these paths are present (e.g. the user is logged in), the path in question will be matched and the corresponding content will be shown.

A word of caution: note that if you plan on providing custom content from your backend, you need to have some safe mechanism in place to know whether the user is really logged in or not, e.g. not just trust a frontend saying "I'm logged in as this and this user". You probably already know that but just making it clear.

Answer (score 1):

i used redux for sign-in, in this case you can write react-router-component, to check that user is logged in or not

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = props;
  return (
    <Route render={(props) => (
      !isLoggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{/loginPage}}>/>
    )} {...props} />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.user.isLoggedIn
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute)
```

Comment: Could you please explain this more? Thank you

Comment: you can use render method inside of a route , i wrote a condition to dynamically check , if user is logged in , route to components, if not, route to login page... then inside of your <Switch> you can import this protectedRoute

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation but I'm using react router v6 so <Switch> doesnt work. But I've updated the codes displayed in my question which is very similar to yours but I still can access my privateRoutes when a user isnt logged in.